# Upgraded to VS 2017 15.6.0 and now Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() returns \bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

After upgrading, it seems all my .net core console apps now get the wrong path when debugging.

I had the following code

```
private static void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
{
        // build configuration
        var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())               
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", false)
            .Build();
}
```

Which would work fine, but now that I upgraded, i get the following error

`System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'The configuration file 'appsettings.json' was not found and is not optional. The physical path is 'D:\projects\myproject\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.0\appsettings.json'.'`

I know I can just copy the appsettings.json to this path but I never had to do that before and it was perfectly fine before the upgrade.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest to remove `.SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())` line at all. `SetBasePath` method is now optional and if it is not called, [then we infer the base path from application base](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/88).

Regarding your error. [There was a fix](https://github.com/dotnet/project-system/pull/3073) in dotnet, that change behavior:

> Changed the default working directory to be the output folder rather than the project root.

Looks like with VS update you have installed the newest version of .NET Core SDK. So you need to copy the appsettings.json to output folder now.

Comment: still getting the same error after removing that line, something happened in the upgrade and now its by default looking at the wrong path when running the project in debug mode

Comment: This will still be required            `.SetBasePath(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location))
` when the app will run from the schedule I assume (I have been using it so far and it seems like its needed)

Comment: Well if they updated that then i guess that answers my question

Comment: If you don't want to copy the resources or fiddle with the paths, then changing the Working directory to .\ on the Debug page of the project might be another option.

Answer (score 1):

Change the appsettings.json files properties "Copy to Output Directory" to be "Copy al"
The appsettings.json files “Copy to Output Directory” property should also be set to “Copy if newer” so that the application is able to access it.

Answer (score 0):

The Startup has changed a little from 1.x to 2.0, you don't use the configuration builder anymore, it's somewhat done mostly behind the scenes however you can declare your `appsettings.json` file in Program.cs

Here is the how-to: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/1x-to-2x/#add-configuration-providers

Comment: That maybe true for asp.net core but I dont think its true for .net core console

Comment: we do use the `ConfigurationBuilder`. Fact that in 2.0 we now have built-in implementation that uses `ConfigurationBuilder` internally doesn't mean that you cannot configure separate config sources by demand.

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

`string Path = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @"..\..\"));`

Simply moves back up two directories from the bin.